# Siunitx incorrect prefixes with inverted range

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to use inverted `\SIrange` but something strange happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--,
     exponent-to-prefix = true,
     zero-decimal-to-integer}
\begin{document}
\SIrange[scientific-notation = engineering]{2000000}{1}{\hertz}
\\
\SIrange[scientific-notation = engineering]{1}{2000000}{\hertz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it a bug and what workaround I can use?

Comment: Well your range in the first case is backward, so I'd say the behaviour is undefined!

Comment: But  how should I create backward range via siunitx? Or there is no proper way to do this task?

Comment: I guess I need to look at the code: I have to say I didn't imagine anyone writing a range backwards ...

Comment: You could just write each number separately and put a hyphen between them.

Comment: Yes, I know about this possibility. I just want to know if there is a  native way to do this trick.

Comment: I believe the backward range should be added because sometimes you want to describe what you see in a diagram. If we have NMR spectra where the higher numbers are on the left and the smaller numbers are on the right, we are supposed to describe them from left-to-right. For Example, a signal could be described as *6.16-6.07 ppm (m, 2 H)*.

Comment: +1 This will be a nice feature to have in siunitx.